# htaccess rules not working on my index.php file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added this rule to my (`htaccess`) file on my root web server so that should anyone try to access lets say `/web server/test` then index would take the 'test' input as string but it is not working it keeps on saying error `404 not found`.

My code is below:

```
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </IfModule>

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Are there any faults in this?

Below is my apache2 conf file.... As I get error 500 after changing my settings to override all.

Now I am getting error 500 ... so that I can provide more information... below is my htaccess file code

```
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </IfModule>

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And my apache2.conf file.....

```
     <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     #Require all denied
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     </Directory>

     <Directory /usr/share>
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
     </Directory>

     <Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
     </Directory>
```

Comment: I also tried looking for setting that have anything to do with htaccess on my apache2.conf file... I seem to not know what to edit and what not to change... I would highly appreciate it and be grateful if anyone can guide me...

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: I did add some garbage and I am still getting error 404 meaning .htaccess is not enabled on my server... How do I enable it? Your advise would appreciated although I will also search on google...

Comment: Every system is different but in short `AllowOverride All` in Apache config takes care of it.

Comment: Also, you need `Options +FollowSymLinks`. But wouldn't your regex match your entire URL ie. `web server/test`?

Answer (score 0):

two key points you need attention .

1. ensure your root directory can be overwrite by apache , please check the apache configuration , correct setting by below:

   ```
   <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
     #AllowOverride none
     AllowOverride All 
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     # Require all denied
   </Directory>
   ```
2. check your rewrite rules and ensure them can work. On your case i test following rules and work fun on my local.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                              
   RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
   ```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: I have edited my question... I did change the conf file I now get error 500 and tried checking the whole file...

Comment: I re-edit my answer , for my local i config the vhost setting. for example  i just mapping the local.demo.com to /var/www/demo in vhost file , then the htaccess file under the /var/www/demo/ dir. so when i access the local.demo.com/test, the url will jump to local.demo.com/index.php?page=test .  so would you please try a test according to my desc ?@Masilo